# highcharts - how to controle slice pie from bottom

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart and need to slice out some point (for examle, second slice in jsfiddle example) by clicking a buttom. How can I do it?
I've tried some updating, but it doesn't work

```
$('#button').click(function() {
var Chart2 = $('container').highcharts();
Chart2.options.series[0].data[1].sliced = true;
Chart2.options.series[0].data[1].selected = true;
Chart2.redraw();        
})
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/junatina/wu3jY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you need is 'select' on the point object. This is on series, but not in options as you tried:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].data[1].select();
})
```

e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/JWFm5/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use slice() function.

http://jsfiddle.net/wu3jY/2/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        chart.series[0].data[0].slice();
});
```